# view-source of a web link in android

Tags: android, facebook, url, android-webview, android-browser

I trying to load `"view-source:http://goo.gl/lEYQQf"` link in webview. If I load this link in google chrome from PC, the link changes into this `"view-source:https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=CAAAACZAVC6ygBAKYZBIixFdEDGOHMUhTMxoBcN4pCaPu137s02iHtD0kgKUlW59cU7qAuLgsIXZBOvJ8OLevA3zArPx8v2TkUxbG493Bq7hMiHKHYZC66cbEvQsDBzhAbZCVIx8jOGUc4k3ynW4f65cUZB6m5IZA5tWrnQhnBcGUHMjKtmLZBpsmBzxOZA9ZCwmFgZD&expires_in=0"`

I need this access token. I have tried this code:

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            Log.e("testing", url);
        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("view-source:http://goo.gl/lEYQQf");
```

This is not loading the url. When I remove the "view-source:" part from the given url, in output it is giving me an another link which does not contains the access token. I have tried two more ways but I am not able to get that token. How can I get it?